# If I'm trying to get error codes from my children processes while I'm using scanf/fgets in the parent process

Tags: c, fork, parent, scanf

Is there a way that I can get the parent process to opt out of the scanf/fgets command? What's happening is I have 11 child processes going and there is an option that leads the child processes to just reach a point, which I make it run into error(100);. The problem is that the parent process is stuck trying to grab some sort of input from the user that it doesn't realize they are actually done.

So is there a way so that if all my child processes run into this error that it can someone relay back that they've all met that specific error code and make the parent function opt out?

EDIT: Also, I'm trying to use things SIG's (SIGALRM, SIGKILL, etc), not piping.

Comment: The parent process could use multiple threads, and a thread waiting for child processes could terminate the thread waiting for input.

Comment: Please post the actual code, the desired output, the actual output.  Otherwise we are just making guesses and/or expressing opinions.